# Error_al_crear_Servicio_PM2_WINDOWS SERVER

Tags: windows, servicio, server, pm2

Buen dia comunidad. Estoy teniendo un problema al crear un servicio con PM2 en un windows server; al terminar el proceso de creacion del servicio y querer ver la lista de pm2, o agregar algun otro comando pm2 me aparece este error:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pienso que puede ser la variable de entorno, pero no estoy muy seguro. A alguno le habra pasado y encontrado una solucion?. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.